# Objects becoming nil after navigating back

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Well, I m passing data between two Views.

On  my first view i just overview data from CD. In my seconde View I can change these data. If I change someting and save it, I return to my first View. So far everything works great.

But I m getting a strange behavior when i m navigating back to my first ViewController from my seconde VC without saving.

The object(a NSManagedObject) that i got as property in my first VC is in my viewWillAppear methode not nil. But in my viewWillAppear methode I call another methode that fills all fields in my VC. In that methode the object is nil now.

I dont understand that behavior, its not nil in the viewWillAppear but in the methode that is getting called by viewWillAppear its nil.

Does someone had this same behavior?

**EDIT 1:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"VIEW WILL APPEAR!!");
    NSLog(@"Eventname: %@", eventObject.name);
    NSLog(@"USERID: %@", appUser.userID);
    [self initViewData];
    [self editViewStyles];
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2013-05-24 18:11:00.082 1![1089:16d03] VIEW WILL APPEAR!!
2013-05-24 18:11:00.083 1![1089:16d03] Eventname: boo
2013-05-24 18:11:00.083 1![1089:16d03] USERID: 54E1EFBE-7BAD-4441-B564-F0CDB9C85998
```

**initViewData**

```
- (void) initViewData{
    NSLog(@"Eventname: %@", eventObject.name);
    NSLog(@"USERID: %@", appUser.userID);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2013-05-24 18:11:00.084 1![1089:16d03] Eventname: (null)
2013-05-24 18:11:00.084 1![1089:16d03] USERID: (null)
```

Comment: please post relevant code.......

Comment: @Piyuesh i updated it :)

Comment: Try set breakpoint in setter of the name and userID. Values may be change in other thread.

Comment: and i dont use threads yet

Comment: How are they declared? strong? weak? ?

Comment: @FrankC. strong, nonatomic..

Comment: How did you get your NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: I have a costum class where all my methodes for CD are.. if a context is nil, I create one.. `    /** one line complete init */
    CoreDataStack* cdStack = [CoreDataStack coreDataStackWithModelName:@"Model"];
    
    /** one property you need for all Core Data method calls */
    if (context == nil) {
        context = cdStack.managedObjectContext;
    }
    return context;`